# Adding Custom Background for Widget Based on User Input

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget that displays a set of information. What I would like to do is to give the user the opportunity to choose the background color/image. I would like to have a popup when the user is selecting the widget to choose the background.

So how would I make the popup?

And how would I apply the background dynamically?

Thank you for any help you can give!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might would be better if you open a PreferenceActivity by tapping the widget.
Then choose the appropriate picture and get the appropriate prefs by using:

```
String background = prefs.getString("background", "bgpink"); // get the Prefs!
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

if (background.equals("bgpink")) {
    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widgetLayout, R.drawable.bgpink); // set the background
}
```

The setBackground code does not work. I read the documentation of "setImageViewResource" and this is an open issue i think. Let me know if you found a solution for setting the background.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this specifically before but I would go about it in the following manner:

- If you are looking to pick up files that are already on the system, fire an intent to pick (ACTION_PICK) and supply the right Intent.data element
- If you are supplying the options:

  - Create a Dialog with a list view (of image view / text view (with compound drawables and some text)) to select the background
  - Store the value returned into a preference file
  - Read from preference and apply Background

Hope this helps

Comment: I see how that suggests a way to prompt the user, but I don't understand how to actually implement the background change.

Comment: I have since found the android:configure options. Thanks :-)

Comment: @atolar, it will be great if you can elaborate on that. I for one will be interested in finding out more about these options

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring has information about a configuration activity for the widget.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using:

```
    public static void setWidgetBackground(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int mAppWidgetId, int newBackground){
            // theLayout is a global int in my case

            switch (newBackground){
            case R.id.brown:
                theLayout = R.layout.brown_widget;
                break;
        case R.id.darkblue:
            theLayout = R.layout.darkblue_widget;
                break;
            case R.id.darkpurple:
                theLayout = R.layout.darkpurple_widget;
                break;
            // ... etc.
            }


            // save the settings so we can load and apply again next time the widget is updated
            WidgetConfigure.saveLayout(context,mAppWidgetId,theLayout);

            // call the actual update so that the right background is applied
            this.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId, theLayout);

    }
```

Hope this is helpful to others.